# Change how the number of selected lines or columns is shown

Tags: vim

Is there a way to change how the number of selected lines or columns is shown?

For example, if I select 2 lines of text, Vim will show me just `2` below the statusline. While I want to change it to `Selected 2 lines`.

And the same way, if I select word `if` in my text, Vim will show me just a `2`, again. But now, I want to change it to `Selected 2 columns`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard-coded : the only way to do it is to modify and recompile the sources.

In Vim's sources, look at `screen.c` : `int showmode(void)` and `normal.c` : `void clear_showcmd(void)`

Comment: Thanks) Maybe you know, is it also true for undo/redo messages (`2 fewer lines; before #5  10 seconds ago`)? So I cannot remove them without recompiling the sources?

Comment: Yes, it's the same